# Dynamic Header Blur Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have a fixed header that I would like to add a dynamic blur as the user scrolls down the page. I learned that the `filter: blur(10px)` only works for elements within the applied div.Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Updated: What I want to do is make anything that is underneath my fixed header appear blurred, not the actual header itself. I think I would have to make parts of the div under the header blurred rather than the whole div to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add dynamicaly a classname with jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $( "#tag" ).addClass( "blurredclass" );
});
```

You can define a variable within scroll function to check offsetTop position, so you can add blurred class after you reach your position

```
var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

**Edit:** you can preview typical solution on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/x2N3N/1/

**Edit2:** if you want to blur text below some position while scrolling:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2N3N/2/

**Edit3:** variant with blurred header:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2N3N/3/

Comment: This doesn't fully answer my question, I want to be able to apply this blur on anything under the header.

Comment: I've done an update on JSFiddle for better understanding, you should be able to apply this solution in your code. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I think we are misunderstanding each other. After a certain amount (100px), I want to the header to blur anything that appears underneath it. In your example, the text would always be clear, but after 100px, whatever text that is underneath the header would become blurred.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry Michael but you should be able to use/modify code I've done for you. I've done another update on JSFiddle. The principle is to add .changed class to element you need to blur. Does not matter if the element is text or header, just set the stop-position and then blur your element.

Comment: Hey I updated my question, I can't mark your answer as correct because it doesn't answer my question, but I upvoted you. Unless you can actually blur the content under my header and not the header itself, I can't accept your answer although it has helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to help you solve your problem. If you want to blur the header background while scrolling the page (e.g. in iOS7 on iphone) the solution exists:

**Using experimental methods:**
http://codepen.io/FWeinb/full/Dfoaw

But problem is compatibility and speed:

1. Chrome 29+ (enable 'experimental-webkit-features'/'enable-experimental-web-platform-features')
2. Safari 6.1 Seed 6
3. iOS7 - slow

**Next method is to blur rendered html in canvas**

More info and example: http://blurpopup.labs.daum.net/

1. run html2canvas for rendering document as an image.
2. Convert image to data-url string and and place it as background-image.
3. apply blur (-webkit-filter:blur ... )
4. Append the bg layer into document with position of document scroll offset.

You can find html2canvas here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ (it's a simple js library)

**I've done complete live example with basic usage:**

http://www.24development.cz/examples/blurred-header/

There are some limitations with html2canvas rendering, but for basic idea there is the point.